# can I apply Cauchy-Schwarz to this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

The question says, if $n \geq 3, k \in \mathbb{R}$, what is the smallest $k$ such that $\forall a_i\in \mathbb{R},  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^3\leq k\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^6}$.

Tried: apply Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to get $k=n$...But is not exactly sure.

Can anyone justify or correct it?

Comment: This is similar to asking for the smallest $k$ such that $\|x\|_1 \le k \|x\|_2$. Look at norm equivalences.

Comment: @copper.hat I didn't see the similarity. $\|x\|_1 = \sum |x_i|$ but here $a_i^3$ could be any real number, positive or negative.

Comment: I added an answer elaborating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sum_k x_k \le \|x\|_1 \le \sqrt{n} \|x\|_2$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Furthermore, if we set $x_k = 1$ for all $k$, we have equality, hence $\sqrt{n}$ is the best bound.

Now let $x_k = a_k^3$. Then the above gives
$\sum_k a_k^3 \le \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\sum_k a_k^6}$.

Comment: Why $\sqrt{n}$ is the 'best' bound by obtaining the equality?

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{n}$ is an upper bound (this is a standard result in norm equivalence). So, to show that it is the best, you need to show a (non-zero) vector for which the bound is attained. If you choose $a_k = 1$, then both sides are $n$, hence this is the lowest bound.